# Hearthstone ranked chest rewards

Tags: hearthstone

Since this season, based on their rank, each player gets a bunch of chests with dust and golden cards in addition to the season's card back. Is this based on your final rank, or highest rank?

I thought it was the former, but my quest page makes me feel otherwise. I'm concerned it might be a bug displaying the wrong number, since I only just dropped a rank.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is based on the highest rank you achieved that season. Dropping ranks will not affect your ranked chest.